# How to filter a Spark dataframe based on datestamp of the file

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Can someone let me know how filter on datestamp on file

I have the following files in their respective folders in Azure Data Lake:

```py
adl://carlslake.azuredatalakestore.net/folderOne/filenr1_1166_2018-12-20%2006-05-52.csv

adl://carlslake.azuredatalakestore.net/folderTwo/filenr2_1168_2018-12-22%2006-07-31.csv
```

I have written the following script that will read all .csv files in both folders, but I only want to read .csv files in their respective folders based on current date.

```py
test1 = spark.read.csv("adl://carlslake.azuredatalakestore.net/folderOne/",inferSchema=True,header=True)
test2 = spark.read.csv("adl://carlslake.azuredatalakestore.net/folderTwo/",inferSchema=True,header=True)
```

Can someone let me know how to tweak the above the read files on the folders based on current date e.g. the two .csv files are 2018-12-20 and 2018-12-22

I thought it might have been written something like

```py
test1 = spark.read.csv("adl://carlslake.azuredatalakestore.net/folderOne/", select(current_date)inferSchema=True,header=True)
```

But that didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.today().date()
test1 = spark.read.csv(f"adl://carlslake.azuredatalakestore.net/
                       folderOne/*_{today}*.csv")
```

Comment: thanks for reaching out. I tried the following test1 = spark.read.csv(f"adl://carlslake.azuredatalakestore.net/testfolder/RAW/*_{today}*.csv), but I got the error message EOL while scanning string literal. There is an arrow pointing at the bracket by. csv) indicating that is where the problem is.

Comment: oops, I forgot the quotes. However, I have now entered the follow `test1 = spark.read.csv("adl://carlslake.azuredatalakestore.net/testfolder/RAW/*_{today}*.csv")` but I'm getting the error that the path doesn't exist when it most certain does exist

Comment: the full error message is as follows: `u'Path does not exist: adl://carlslake.azuredatalakestore.net/testfolder/RAW/*_{today}*.csv;'`

Comment: I tested just to make sure I wasn't pointing at the wrong path by entering the following `test1 = spark.read.csv("adl://carlslake.azuredatalakestore.net/testfolder/RAW/")` and I didn't get any errors. Only get the path error when I enter `test1 = spark.read.csv("adl://carlslake.azuredatalakestore.net/testfolder/RAW/*_{today}*.csv")`

Comment: Well, I think there're basically two certain ways to achieve what you need. The first one is get all the paths first (with alternative way), filter only those you are interested and pass this list to spark.read.csv or you may use sc.wholeTextFiles to read a whole directory (this would return pair rdd with paths as names and contents of the files as values), filter only those you need and transform values into dataframes.

Comment: Is the syntax correct? `test1 = spark.read.csv("adl://carlslake.azuredatalakestore.net/testfolder/RAW/*_{today}*.csv")`

Comment: Yes, but you forgot `f` at the beginning of the string.

Comment: the missing f was the problem. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Just go with

```
test1 = spark.read.csv("adl://carlslake.azuredatalakestore.net/testfolder/RAW/*{today}.csv"
```

The other pattern `*_{today}*.csv` was not matching your file example above `filenr1_1166_2018-12-20%2006-05-52.csv`

Comment: I should have tested this before marking it successful. Unfortunately it didn't work. I entered `test5 = spark.read.csv("adl://carlslake.azuredatalakestore.net/testfolder/RAW/*{today}.csv")` as you suggested however I'm getting the error `u'Path does not exist: adl://carlslake.azuredatalakestore.net/testfolder/RAW/*{today}.csv;'`